# Unable to fetch some archives (503 Service Unavailable)

Tags: raspbian, packages, vlc

I recently got a Raspberry Pi and have been trying to install some apps on it. I tried installing gnash using:

```
sudo apt-get install iceweasel browser-plugin-gnash
```

but following error message appeared:

```
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libass4 armhf 0.10.0-3
  503  Service Unavailable
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/liba/libass/libass4_0.10.0-3_armhf.deb  503  Service Unavailable
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I also tried installing VLC using:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

but showed same error message as above.

The weird thing is if I go to http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/liba/libass/libass4_0.10.0-3_armhf.deb in my internet browser, it doesnt display a 503 Service Unavailable message and the archive downloads.

Is there a fix? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps DNS resolution failure? You can find some help [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/24125)